# Rolling two dice, find $E[Z]$ given by $Z=|X-Y|$

Tags: probability, dice

> Roll two fair six-sided dice, and let $X$, $Y$ denote the values of the first and the second die, respectively. If  $Z=|X-Y|$, find $E[Z]$.

Comment: Do you want to compute $E[Z]$?

Comment: please include your attempt.

Comment: first clearly i don't understand the question what roll we have to select

Comment: The question wants you to find the expected value of the absolute differences between your first roll and your second. Additionally, given your question record, I would strongly advise trying to show some work, seeing as it looks a little like you're just uploading homework questions for answering.

Comment: @Atul You roll consecutively two die. $X$ is the random variable for the number of the first die and $Y$ is the random variable for the number of the second die. The first step is finding the pdf of $|X-Y|$

Comment: @Atul Are you really interested do some work by your own? Or do you just wait for an answer that contains the solution like below?

Answer (score 2):

$P(|X-Y|=0)=\frac{6}{36}$ (all doubles)

$P(|X-Y|=1)= \frac{10}{36}$ (all pairs with difference 1, so $(1,2),\ldots,(5,6),(6,5), \ldots,(2,1)$, of which there are $10$)

$P(|X-Y|=2)= \frac{8}{36}$

$P(|X-Y|=3) = \frac{6}{36}$

$P(|X-Y|=4)= \frac{4}{36}$

$P(|X-Y|=5)=\frac{2}{36}$ (just $(1,6),(6,1)$)

So the expectation is

$$\sum_{i=0}^5 i \cdot P(|X-Y|=i)$$ which can now be computed.

Comment: The answer E(Z) is 0+0.27+0.44+0.5+0.4+0.27= 1.92

Comment: What´s the problem? Just use the last line.

Comment: @callculus the last substitution I leave to the OP

Comment: @HennoBrandsma OK, I do it as well.

Comment: The distribution of  Z  is  P(Z=0)=6/36,P(Z=1)=10/36,P(Z=2)=8/36,P(Z=3)=6/36,P(Z=4)=4/36,P(Z=5)=2/36 
The expectation of  Z  is  35/18=1.9444